# Will ActionbarSherlock in APK file of my own project?

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock

I am developing a Android application which is supposed to be run on **Android 2.1 API 7** and above.

My question is, if I use [ActionbarSherlock](http://actionbarsherlock.com/) library to implement the Action bar on **API 7**, will the final build **APK** file include the **sherlock** library? Or not?

I mean if I install my application on **Android 2.1** by only use the build **APK** file, will the **sherlock** library be included in it? If not, how to solve the problem?

Basically, I want to use sherlock library to implement action bar and I want to finally install my application which has action bar by using *.apk* file.

Answer (score 3):

Short answer: yes.

Any library that is properly referenced in your project (as explained [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/projects/index.html)) will be built into the .apk; the user doesn't have to install the library separately or anything.